# A fair dice is tossed until a number greater than $4$ appears. The probability that an even number of tosses will be required is

Tags: probability

A fair dice is tossed until a number greater than $4$ appears. The probability that an even number of tosses will be required is:
$A. 1/2$
$B. 3/5$
$C. 1/5$
$D. 2/3$

What I did: The probability should be $(2/3)*(1/3)+(2/3)*(2/3)*(2/3)*(1/3)+(2/3)*(2/3)(2/3)*(2/3)*(2/3)*(1/3)+...$, which should be $2/5$.

But this answer doesn't match with the options. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: the infinity symbol at the end should not be there

Comment: Does greater means strictly greater?

Comment: That just means that the summation is going till infinity. And greater means strictly greater.

Comment: I just ran a brute force and over a million iterations, I got {Odd: 599498, Even: 400502}, which agrees with your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't go wrong. The probability of "success" is 1/3, so the probability of succeding in $2k$ tosses  is

$$\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{2k-1} \frac{1}{3}$$

And
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{2k-1} \frac{1}{3}=\frac{1}{3} \frac{3}{2}\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac{4}{9}\right)^k =\frac{1}{2} \frac{4/9}{1-4/9}=\frac{2}{5}$$

Answer (score 4):

I agree with you.  You have a geometric series that sums to $\frac 25$  Another way to check is that the probability of an even number is $\frac 23$ the probability of an odd number, because you have to start with four or less (probability $\frac 23$), then hit an odd number.  This also gives $\frac 25$ as the answer.

Comment: Thanks..! Probably the textbook is wrong.

Comment: Dang, I should have read your answer first.